# How can Hungarian characters be used in translations of field labels within extension sr_feuser_register

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Hungarian characters aren't displayed correctly when used in translations within sr_feuser_register. The characters are displayed correctly when used in regular content elements.

- sr_feuser_register: 4.0.2
- TYPO3: 6.2
- PHP 5.6
- MySQL 5.5

The website is a single tree, multilanguage site, languages are assigend to domains.

Here is the TS Setup for Hungarian language, other languages have been setup the same way:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 15]
  config.sys_language_uid = 15
  config.language = hu
  config.htmlTag_langKey = hu
  config.locale_all = hu_HU.utf8
[global]
```

sr_feuser_register translations are defined through Typoscript the following way:

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister._LOCAL_LANG.hu {
  username = Felhasználónév
  ...
}
```

When viewed in fronted, the sepcial characters are displayed incorrect. Output is something like: FelhasznĂĄlĂłnĂŠv

Same procedure works fine in other languages. Special characters are displayed correctly when viewing Chinese, German or Russian translation. Characters are stored correctly in the database (utf8_general_ci). Even more strange, when I use the characters in the same Typoscript for a language like french, the charachters are displayed correctly on the french frontend.

Example for french configuration in the same Typoscript Setup Template.

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister._LOCAL_LANG.fr {
  username = Felhasználónév
  ...
}
```

All characters appear correct in french frontend. I have no idea at which point the characters get messed up and why the characters are displayed correctly when used in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Looks very strange indeed, I do not have a proper solution to provide, but are you able to debug the extension's core?

Could you try to modify these lines and see what happens?

https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/sr_feuser_register/blob/162bad24641ea809297f0ef8aa787f1dee281385/Classes/View/Marker.php#L479

Comment: I am able to access the ext folder and could modify the lines you mentioned. What modification would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... first it looks for me that the metaCharset (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#metacharset) is not set to `utf-8`.

Please check that.

Also check if the collation of your database it correct set to utf-8.

Are german umlauts like `äöü` correct displayed?

Comment: Metacharset is set <meta charset="utf-8">. Collation of the database is utf8_general_ci. Umlauts are displayed correctly in the german version.

Comment: have you wrote the hungari typoscript in an external file? is this file utf-8 encoded?

Comment: The hungarian typoscript part is written in a template via the backend. I have tried an utf-8 encoded external file as well, did not make a difference. The really strange thing is that the characters are displayed correctly when used in another language, configured in the same template.